# GPIO on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberrypi

I am running ubuntu on a raspberry pi and I cannot figure out how to activate the GPIO pins. I am trying to activate a python script with a button press.

Here is my script:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(18)
    if input_state == False:
    os.system('python backup.py')
        time.sleep(0.2)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

When I run this I get an error that says; no such import as import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

In the terminal type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python-pip python-dev
pip install --user RPi.GPIO
```

If you are using Python 3.x run these commands.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python3-pip python3-dev
pip3 install --user RPi.GPIO
```

The [raspberry-gpio-python examples](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Examples/) are worth reading. In the [Inputs](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/) example there is this code snippet:

```
while GPIO.input(channel) == GPIO.LOW:
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

It waits 10 ms to give CPU a chance to do other things.

Comment: why `sudo apt-get upgrade`? seems like that is completely unnecessary

Comment: Because python-pip is a third-party package manager and therefore inherently less stable than using apt to install software from the default repositories, I would prefer to update all the other software before installing pip.

Comment: does this add the /dev/gpio device as seen in the raspbian kernel or this this a python workaround?

Comment: RPi.GPIO Python package provides a class to control the GPIO on a Raspberry Pi.