# How to use raspberry pi gpio pin with using ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: 18.04, server, python, raspberrypi, ros

I am using raspberry pi 4 model and I installed ubuntu 18.04.5 OS . I am working with ROS where all the related package I installed and it is working but after that I want to run motor by using raspberry pi GPIO pin but it is not working?

is any one help me to solve that issue? how I can run my motor with ubuntu 18.04.5?
your valuable help will be appreciated.
Thank-you.

Comment: 20.04 and older: https://askubuntu.com/questions/621134/gpio-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: 21.04 and newer: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/gpio-on-raspberry-pi