# Does Ubuntu 23.10 support GPIO on raspberry pi 5 in Python

Tags: python3, raspberrypi, 23.10

If so anyone have an example for gpio 2 button press

Comment: Please add details what you intent to achieve. The question is currently to broad and unclear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GPIO on raspberry pi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621134/gpio-on-raspberry-pi)